# Java Node class for a Graph

Tags: java, graph

I'm using `ArrayList<Nodes>` to store adjacent nodes, and `ArrayList<Integer>` to store the corresponding weights of the vertices. Is this efficient if I only use it for small inputs? Is it efficient for large inputs as well?

```
class Node {
    public ArrayList<Node> adjacent = new ArrayList<Node>();
    public ArrayList<Integer> weights = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    boolean visited;
}
```

Comment: It is one of the popular data structure for storing graphs - AdjencyList. So far it seems good.

Comment: I had seen some classes where they created classes for vertices as well, I found it too complicated, I guess this should work and no more classes should be needed

Comment: do you mean edges? Because here Node is a vertex and weights I believe are the weight for the edges going to adjacent nodes.

Depending on problem you might need to create a class for edges too, for e.g. if edges have some extra data your problem like cost, distance and other metrics. In that case, your weights will become an array list of the Edge class

Comment: Yes I meant edges. Sorry for the confusion, can I not save that data in the node, like suppose in Node A adjacent matrix element x is Node B. Edge connecting A to B has some weight, we can store that as element x in another array. This would be applicable to unidirectional Graph, in case of bidirectional, a lot of data would be redundant but again for small number of input it will just work.

Comment: Also a sidenote, using a generic List to store integers can be very inefficient, as you will be dealing with boxing.

Comment: If the core of the question is whether the data structure is OK: Yes. As others have pointed out, this is an [adjacency list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_list). Depending on the desired genericity, one would/could/should try to add an abstraction layer to hide this implementation detail from the user, but this is not trivial (and may not be necessary in your case). If the question is about "low level code recommendations": It should be `private final List<Node> adjacent` (+ the necessary accessor methods)

Answer (score 2):

> Is this efficient if I only use it for small inputs?

For small inputs, anything is efficient. 
For big data, having each `Node` as such a large object would be inefficient.
I depends what kind of actions you would do over the graph. If you access it sequentially, there can be also a linked implementation like:

```
class LinkedNode {
    public Node firstChild;   
    public Node nextSibling;   
    boolean visited;
}
```

Here's an alternative, without objects but with arrays instead:

```
int[] edgeWeights;
int[] edgeIndicies;
```

At the begin, `edgeIndicies` will have values `[0,1,2,...n]`.
Sorting the weights, you move the indicies instead, so if the indicies are the following:
`[5,7,9,...]` you know `edgeWeights[5]` is the smallest, `edgeWeights[7]` is the second smallest, ...etc.